# Trying to create Data frame from a file with delimiter '|'

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to load a text file which has delimiter "|" into Dataframe in spark.
one way is to create the RDD and use toDF to create Dataframe. However I was wondering if I can create DF directly.
As of now I am using the below command

```
val productsDF = sqlContext.read.text("/user/danishdshadab786/paper2/products/")
```

Comment: which version of spark are you using?

Comment: why does your input filename end with a slash?

Answer (score 3):

#### For Spark 2.x

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("delimiter", "|")
      .load("/user/danishdshadab786/paper2/products/")
```

#### For Spark<2.0

```
val df = sqlContext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("delimiter", "|")
      .load("/user/danishdshadab786/paper2/products/")
```

You can add more options like `option("header", "true")` for reading headers in the same statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the delimiter in the 'read' options:

```
spark.read
.option("delimiter", "|")
.csv("/user/danishdshadab786/paper2/products/")
```